# Parsing XML in chunks using NSXMLParser

Tags: ios, xml, nsxmlparser

I'd like to use `NSXMLParser` to parse a large xml file. There are a few thousand elements on the root level, so it's too large for a tree based approach. Ideally, I would like to parse each of those one thousand elements individually into a tree and then do some (more complicated) parsing on them. I only need the string values (including the xml markup) of these root level elements which I can then hand off to my already existing tree based parser. I wasn't able to find out how to do that with `NSXMLParser`, if possible at all.

Imagine an xml file like this

```
<start>
 <record>
  <title>The Title</title>
  <content>Some content</content>
 </record>
 <record>
  <title>The Title</title>
  <content>Some content</content>
 </record>
</start>
```

For each `record`, I'd like to get a string containing `<title>The Title</title> <content>Some content</content>`.

Comment: I found a possible answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735590/ios-combining-sax-and-dom-parsing

Comment: NSXMLParser does exactly what you want, so I don't know what the problem is.  It will spit out the info as it goes along, and it is up to you to do something with it.  It returns info via delegate methods.

Comment: No it does not. In the above example it parses the <title> and <content> elements. I just want the string `<title>The Title</title> <content>Some content</content>`.

Comment: You mean you want one string containing both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rewriting everything as a SAX parser. It is slightly more complicated to implement and fairly restrictive, but the speed up and memory usage is really worth it in my case.